# Inherit from control and create custom one

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im inheriting from GridView control creating MyGridView class which has cs extension, not ascx. U put it in App_Code folder and in web config added:

```
<add tagPrefix="mgv" namespace="MyProject"/>
```

it works fine but when I wanted to convert it to web site project I have problem that it cannot find this reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an assembly reference, set it to assembly="App_Code" was one trick that I've seen done.